# Disable auto focus on first item in GuidedStepSupportFragment from Leanback library

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Is there a good way to disable focus on first item when activity with `GuidedStepSupportFragment` opened? Im starting this activity on long click so i don't need to proceed this click on the new screen.

The only i can do now is to add dummy focusable item, but this seems like a crutch.